# How to reference a local file in a NativeScript mobile app

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I am trying to read from a .txt file located within the project structure. After the app has been compiled to the device (tested on both Android and iOS), I begin by checking if the file exists. It does not seem to.

fileAccess.ts:

```
import fs = require("file-system");

export class FileAccess
{
    public data(filePath: string)
    {
        let exists = fs.File.exists(filePath);
        console.log(exists);
    }
}
```

test.txt (located in same directory as fileAccess.ts):

```
1;DAC
```

Calling `data("./test.txt");` on an instance of `FileAccess`, the console prints **false**.

I assume that either I am referencing the file wrong, or the file is not being copied to the device. But which is it, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `knownFolders` for that. Assuming `test.txt` is in the root of the `app` folder:

`let appPath = fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path;
let myTextFile = appPath + "/test.txt"`

Comment: Thanks Eddy for all your work! Just a silly question - in my angular project the `app` folder is under `src` and the file is not found. Where shell I put it?

Comment: @MartinDimitrov - I know this is a really old post, but I've been building an NS app this year and currently having the same issue.  Cannot figure out where files are on my PC or on my Device.  I used knownFolders.currentApp().path along with file.writeText("hello"), and the file is persisting somewhere but cannot locate it.  

I know it exists because I then run the app with only file.readText() and it displays "hello", - no idea, already spent hours trying to figure out where the file is getting saved with no luck did you get your issue resolved?

Comment: @Robert sorry, I wasn’t able to find a solution. We didn’t continue with NS so I didn’t dig further